# pg_dump does not write "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

We have dumped a database that uses the postgis extension using pg_dump. After manually creating the database on a different machine an attempt to load the dump into it using psql failed. It turned out the dump did not contain the necessary statement

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

The postgis extension was installed in the target instance of Postgres but only after manual execution of the `CREATE EXTENSION` loading of the dump succeeded. This doesn't seem like a big deal, but the question is: is it possible to force `pg_dump` to write all required `CREATE EXTENSION foo;` statements into the dump so I don't have to do it manually? I don't see any option for that in `pg_dump` online documentation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Several possibilities:

1. This database has been upgraded from an old version where `CREATE EXTENSION` did not yet exist.
2. Somebody mistakenly installed PostGIS by executing the SQL script rather than running `CREATE EXTENSION`.
3. You don't dump the whole database, but restrict the dump to a schema using the `-n` option (if you limit the dump to a schema, it will not dump extensions even if the extension schema is among the dumped schemas).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to dump schema and extensions (tested on 11.2):

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d mydb -s > dump.sql
```

Comment: The extensions are dumped this way, albeit not in the proper order. A line of SQL tries to create an index before the extensions are created: `USING gin (address_line_1 public.gin_trgm_ops);`.  Fails with: ` ERROR:  operator class "public.gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"` in my case. Also PG 11.17.