# Why PostgreSQL extension was not dumped when created from `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*` script?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, postgresql-extensions

I created extensions from `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*` script like this:

```sql
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname db <<EOSQL
  CREATE EXTENSION citext;
  CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
  CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
  CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
  CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
EOSQL
```

****Sorry, we used outdated image. Actual command is:**

```sql
gosu postgres postgres --single -jE <<EOSQL
  CREATE EXTENSION citext;
  CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
  CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
  CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
  CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
EOSQL
```

When I dump this database with `pg_dumpall/pg_dump` extensions does not exists in dump file and database restore fails.

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d userdb
pg_dumpall -U postgres
```

But if I connect to my database and do `DROP/CREATE extension` then my extensions are dumped and database successfully restored. My PostgreSQL server version is 11.12.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453662/4632019) and I do not understand p2. Does my `CREATE EXTENSION` counted as SQL script? If yes, why and how to make it non script?

Comment: How do you create the backup? What is the exact command you use for pg_dump?

Comment: @FrankHeikens: the question was updated

Comment: Works for me. Not sure what goes wrong on your end, but maybe you're connected to the wrong environment.  In your current connection string, you leave out almost all information, falling back to the different defaults. Try to be specific in your connection string, without any assumptions about defaults. The correct ip address, port number, etc.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: I am inside docker container with my database. Ok. will try to provide -h -p explicitly, but I do not have other database on this AWS VPC.

Comment: Possible explanations: 1) the script creating the extensions fails and the `CREATE EXTENSION` are rolled back 2) you are dumping a different database

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Thank you. 1) No, the script does not fail and extensions are created; 2) No, this is the only postgresql server with only database (except default). See the solution I found in my answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I can provide logs.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that your solution first drops the extensions. That is OK. I also see now that you edited the question, and you ran PostgreSQL in single-user mode (whatever that `gosu` is). And you used `-j`, which means "Use semicolon followed by two newlines, rather than just newline, as the command entry terminator." I see no two newlines in your script...

Answer (score 0):

I resolution I created next `999-recreate-extensions.sh` initialization script. Here I created extensions via `psql`:

```
gosu postgres pg_ctl -D "$PGDATA" -o "-c listen_addresses='' -p 5432" -w start

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname db <<EOSQL
 DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS pg_trgm;
 DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS unaccent;
 DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS hstore;
 DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS pgcrypto;
 DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS citext;
EOSQL


psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname db -c "CREATE EXTENSION citext;"
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname db -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;"
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname db -c "CREATE EXTENSION hstore;"
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname db -c "CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;"
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname db -c "CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;"

echo "EXTENSIONS Were reinstalled";

gosu postgres pg_ctl -D "$PGDATA" -m fast -w stop
```

After this following `pg_dumpall` dumps `CREATE EXTENSION` statements.